# Peer video not loading, Kurento Media Server , with Ubuntu 16

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, kurento

Installed kurento media server 6.6.2 on Ubuntu 16 using following link

https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.6.2/installation_guide.html

[image]

As seen in the image the connections are established but video is not loading as shown in the image 
[image]

Demo code can be downloaded from
https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.10.0/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2one.html

Comment: Same installation work successfully on ubuntu 14 but shows problem in ubuntu 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kurento was not able to put the remote video,  as the network may be behind the NAT. so one needs to add STURN/TURN links. [Click here](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/user/faq.html) for reference